# abspath returns different results when py_compile input path is different in Python?

Tags: python, linux

I want to know abspath of python script followed by steps below.

1. **built it to byte code by py_compile.**
2. **execute it to check abspath.**

But I got **2 results** when I execute it.I found the **results based on the path of script** followed by py_compile.

Here is my script test.py :

```
import os
import inspect

print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
```

Build it with py_compile, then got 2 results when I enter **different path of test.py**:

**1.enter the folder and compile with only script name.Then chdir to execute**

```
[~]cd /usr/local/bin/
[/usr/local/bin/]python -m py_compile test.py
[/usr/local/bin/]cd ~
[~]python /usr/local/bin/test.pyc
/home/UserXX
```

**2.In other folder and compile with absolute script name.**

```
[~]python -m py_compile /usr/local/bin/test.py
[~]python /usr/local/bin/test.pyc
/usr/local/bin
```

how come got 2 different results?

Answer (score 1):

When we want to get the path of one python file, typically we can use any of following methods:

**1.**

a)

```
import os
import inspect
print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))).replace('\\', '/')
```

b)

```
import os
import inspect
print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.stack()[0][1])).replace('\\', '/')
```

**2.**

a)

```
import os
import sys
print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)).replace('\\', '/')
```

b)

```
import os
import sys
print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])).replace('\\', '/')
```

For most of scenarios, we use `1` is enough, we seldom to use inspect like `2`, as `inspect` maybe slower.

**When will we use 2? Say use inspect to get file path?**

One scenario I can remember is `execfile`, when `fileA.py` execfile `fileB.py` in its program, and `fileA` & `fileB` not in the same folder. (Maybe more scenario)

Then if we use `__file__` in `fileB.py`, you will find its directory is just same as `fileA.py`, because here the directory will be the caller's directory.
Then we had to use `inspect` to get `fileB.py`'s directory.

Anyway, for your situation, if your `test.py` just at the top of callgraph, just suggest you to use `__file__`, it's quicker, no need to use `inspect`.
With this if you use `-m py_compile`, it works for you.

**Finally, why inspect not work with -m py_compile?**

Unfortunately, I did not find official document to explain this.
But suppose your `test.py` is in the folder `tt`, then let's do `cd ..; python -m py_compile tt/test.py`, you will get a `test.pyc` in `tt` folder.

Let open this pyc file, although you will see something not suitable for man to read, you still can find some clue:
One line is something like:
`currentframe(^@^@^@^@(^@^@^@^@(^@^@^@^@s^G^@^@^@tt/a.pyt`

Do you see the folder name tt already in pyc file?
If you use `inspect.stack()` to test, it will more clear, `print inspect.stack()[0][1]` will always take your current compile folder in pyc file if you use `-m py_compile`.
This directly means during the process of `py_compile`, something was fixed to pyc file. This something I call `fix` makes you can just run your program in the same folder you do `-m py_compile`.

Hope this can give you some clue & helps you.

Comment: I agree with your observation.py_compile fix the currentframe.In the 1st situation, inspect.getfile will get test.py. abspath will return normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path)) when input has no slashes. so abspath return /home/UserXX cuz os.getcwd() is the current working dir.